# JavaFX: Why does text turn 'rainbow' when small

Tags: css, javafx, text, combobox, label

[image: screenshot]

The text above uses the JavaFX control 'Text' which does not turn rainbow.

The text below uses the JavaFX control 'ComboBox' which turns into rainbow - also turns into rainbow for control 'Label' as well.

When I enlarge the font size over a certain amount (approx 100px), the 'rainbow' effect is no longer there (or at least visible).

I've tried using different fonts, but this problem is universal to all fonts

I use it like this:

```
@FXML
JFXComboBox<String> algorithmCombo;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    ObservableList<String> algorithmList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "A* Pathfinder", "Dijkstra's Pathfinder", "Bubble Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Merge Sort", "Quick Sort", "Linear Search", "Binary Search");
    algorithmCombo.setItems(algorithmList);
    algorithmCombo.setValue(algorithmList.get(0));
}
```

The above is fine, it gives no rainbow, but the text is black by default. So I change it's text colour by applying a CSS style on the combo box

style.css

```
.jfx-combo-box .cell {
    -fx-font: 15px "Caviar Dreams";
    -fx-text-fill: white; 
    -fx-background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

Comment: Are you doing `ComboBox<Text> comboBox = new ComboBox();`?

Comment: No I drag and drop a ComboBox in Scenebuilder and give it an fx id like myCombo. Then in the controller I do @FXML JFXComboBox<String> myCombo; to retrive it

Comment: Your question mentioned `ComboBox` but the code you've provided is using `JFXComboBox` from, I assume, JFoenix. Does the same problem occur with the default `ComboBox` control?

Comment: If you are using `ComboBox<String>`, my answer is not irrelevant. I took it down.